# Connection examples and embedding dimension theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, low-dimensional-topology, mobius-band, klein-bottle

I've read about the "Utility Problem" (i.e. three utilities and three customers) requiring three dimensions to accomplish/attaching/embedding; and the Klein bottle requiring four (space-like) dimensions.  Presumably this relates to embedding.
My question is: how to prove that particular connection/attachment problems throw the "manifold" into higher dimensions.  The example of the Klein bottle has a  two-dimensional domain/surface, but pushes the embedding space into four dimensions.
References are fine, since I am trying to learn and have a particular problem in mind; and it would seem to require detailed knowledge.  My background is one quarter of point-set topology, which doesn't seem to cover this.

Comment: I don't see in which sense embedding the Klein bottle in euclidean space is a "connection problem" akin to the three utilities problem. These two are pretty disparate problems in terms of how they're usually treated (one is a question of graph theory, the other a question of topology), although you can recast them in uniform language with a bit of work. Are you asking for references proving these specific claims or for references discussing embeddings into Euclidean space more generally? In the latter case, do you really care about embeddings of graphs or about manifolds?

Comment: I think Klein bottle is irrelevant here. "Connection" is also a wrong terminology. I suspect, you are asking about generalization of the obstructions to embeddings in higher-dimensional Euclidean spaces which are similar to the ones coming from the existence of $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ subgraphs in the case of the planarity problem for graphs. If so, yes (work of Van Kampen, Flores and many others), but you first have to learn some algebraic topology to understand how this works.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I do have an Algebraic Topology book; and I will take it up again. I put it aside because it _just_ covered decomposition, but I see that was an ignorant conclusion. The reason I wrote "connections" was that they (Klein/Möbius/Utility) had to do with attachments; i.e. the Klein bottle is a finite cylinder attached to itself in a particular way, and the Möbius strip is similar. My problem could be said to be: how to construct a 4/3 dimensional manifold/object that demands attachments in higher (say 6) dimensions? I will modify the question so nobody else misinterprets.

Comment: You are using some very nonstandard language. My suggestion is to keep learning AT (Massey or Hatcher), so that you are comfortable with the language, know main definition and basic results. Then revisit your question. You are just not ready for this discussion. Sorry for being so blunt.

Comment: "blunt"?   I did ask for references to learn from :)

Comment: Regarding reference, here is Hatcher's book, freely available: https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html

Comment: Found it :)  and am reading it.  BTW: ultimately what I am hoping to do is find a counter-example to a physics problem/conclusion/interpretation; or prove there isn't one.  I've stewed on it for a couple of years and decided to actually give it a try.

Comment: Here's a [random relevant paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.0336) that I haven't read, only paged through, but looks good. It's specifically about how algorithmically complex it is to decide whether or not a simplicial complex (both graphs and the Klein bottle may be regarded as examples) can be embedded in a particular dimension of Euclidean space. It suggests background material in a footnote on the first page.

Comment: @KyleMiller Thanks, that seems to be what I was looking for; but I still have to learn a lot :)  If you know how, I will move your comment to the answer section.  If true, it's a little disappointing.  "Theorem 1.3. EMBEDk→d is NP-hard for every pair (k, d) with d ≥ 4 and d ≥ k ≥ 2d−2
3
."  I guess it might be related/similar to Chaitin's work and the yes/no of a finite number of solutions to Diophantine equations; although his examples are algorithmically more challenging.  But I haven't given up hope for a simple example; i.e extending Klein.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I found Hatcher's book quite dense and hard to get traction; not that I think it's a bad book!  I did find "Algebraic Topology: An Introduction" by Massey on Amazon for a reasonable price (US$20) but it's gone back up in price.  It's definitely a more direct way into my mind.   Thanks for the references again!  (I have no idea how the "market" thinks these books should be priced; like we are all "collectors", not  readers.)